# Where does Jupyter Notebook save files?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

So I'm just beginning my programming/coding journey. I've downloaded Anaconda and made a shortcut for Jupyter Notebook on my desktop. I tried using my first file the other day, and I'm not sure where it's being saved to. Also, I basically don't want Jupyter to save any Notebook I do once I close the Notebook, unless I specifically save it myself - I just use it for 'working out' if you like.

[Here is the image showing what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW4VH.png)

Like, *where* is that untitled.ipynb file being saved? And, how can I adjust my settings in Jupyter Notebook such that these files aren't saved and are discarded automatically so I can use them as I describe just for 'working out'?

Answer (score 5):

By default the ipynb files are stored to your user profile:

```
C:\Users\yourlogin
```

How to disable autosave has already been described here:

[Turn Off Autosave in IPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631344/turn-off-autosave-in-ipython-notebook)

I don't recommend doing that.

Comment: Why don't you recommend doing that? I just use it for temporary 'working out' a lot of the time so I don't want it saving all those files.

Also, do you know where these files are being saved in Spyder? And how to turn it off there?

Finally, I just downloaded Anaconda, with these softwares. However when I load up Spyder it says a newer version of it is available, so I updated it through Anaconda - is that okay? Or should I revert to the old version (if so, how would I do that lol?)

Thanks!